# Set MySQL default time zone to UTC

Tags: mysql

I want to set the default time zone of my MySQL install to UTC. My system time zone is Australia/Brisbane, and I want to leave it that way, I just want to set the default time zone for MySQL. I've added the following line to `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
default_time_zone=UTC
```

but now my mysql.service doesn't start.

`systemctl start mysql.service` gives me:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status mysql.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status mysql.service` tells me:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-01-11 09:36:12 AEST; 11s ago
  Process: 556 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 549 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 556 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE); Control PID: 557 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─557 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─606 sleep 1

Jan 11 09:36:12 irregular-apocalypse systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 11 09:36:14 irregular-apocalypse systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

`journalctl -xe` gives me:

```
Jan 11 09:37:15 irregular-apocalypse systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Jan 11 09:37:15 irregular-apocalypse audit[757]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/757/status" pid=757 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ouid=
Jan 11 09:37:15 irregular-apocalypse audit[757]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=757 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=
Jan 11 09:37:15 irregular-apocalypse audit[757]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/757/status" pid=757 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ouid=
Jan 11 09:37:15 irregular-apocalypse kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515627435.055:544): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/757/status" pid=757 comm="mysqld" requested_mask
Jan 11 09:37:15 irregular-apocalypse kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515627435.055:545): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=757 comm="mysqld" reque
Jan 11 09:37:15 irregular-apocalypse kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515627435.055:546): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/757/status" pid=757 comm="mysqld" requested_mask
Jan 11 09:37:16 irregular-apocalypse systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

I've looked into the apparmor errors and have concluded that they are not contributing to my problem, as those same errors are present if I remove the `default_time_zone` config item and start the server:

```
Jan 11 09:40:14 irregular-apocalypse systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Jan 11 09:40:14 irregular-apocalypse audit[1516]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1516/status" pid=1516 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ou
Jan 11 09:40:14 irregular-apocalypse audit[1516]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=1516 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsui
Jan 11 09:40:14 irregular-apocalypse audit[1516]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1516/status" pid=1516 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ou
Jan 11 09:40:14 irregular-apocalypse kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515627614.793:562): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1516/status" pid=1516 comm="mysqld" requested_ma
Jan 11 09:40:14 irregular-apocalypse kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515627614.793:563): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=1516 comm="mysqld" requ
Jan 11 09:40:14 irregular-apocalypse kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1515627614.793:564): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1516/status" pid=1516 comm="mysqld" requested_ma
Jan 11 09:40:15 irregular-apocalypse systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
```

The only file that I have in `/var/log/mysql` is `error.log`, and it does not contain anything relating to the failed startup. I cannot find any *.err or *.log files in my data directory (`/var/lib/mysql`).

I've purged and reinstalled mysql-server multiple times with no effect.

My question is really two:

1. Is this the correct way to set the default_time_zone for MySQL? If not, how do I do it?
2. Failing an answer to question 1 resolving my problem, how do I find out what's causing the error in MySQL starting?

OS: Ubuntu Desktop 17.10

MySQL: 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was that I hadn't populated the time zone tables. Running this command fixed my problem:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/ | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Comment: Would be nice if this was somehow handled in the default setup of the ubuntu mysql-server package (debconf?).

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't figure out why +01:00 was working, but "Europe/Copenhagen" wasn't. I had overridden the mysql container entrypoint, which likely sets this up.